# Looping inside dialog box elements using tab key not working in Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webkit, modal-dialog

I am having a pop up dialog box that has buttons and input fields that can be navigated by tabs. **Once the focus reaches the last element, I want to return the focus to the first element of the dialog box**. I don't want the focus to leave the dialog box. 
I know it can be handled using jquery ui but I have already created lot of popups and I want a solution **without jquery ui dialogs**.

I have implemented a generic solution using jquery. I add an  element without any visible text at the end of the dialog and when the focus reaches this element, I return the focus to the first element.

```
<input id="firstElement" type="text"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit"/>
<a id="lastHiddenElement" href="#"/>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lastHiddenElement').focus(function(){
        $('#firstElement').focus();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WVDz3/7/

But this works only in Firefox and IE and does not work in Safari and Chrome. This seems to be a bug(usability) in webkit

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=168121

If I add the anchor tag with visible text it works in webkit too.

jsfiddle.net/WVDz3/9/

But I want to navigate without showing any unwanted elements to the user.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your last element with `opacity: 0;`

This will make it invisible and will work with your current jQuery script

You should also know, that if you want your `a` to be set on focus it needs some text :

HTML :

```
<a id="lastHiddenElement" href="#">hidden</a>
```

CSS:

```
#lastHiddenElement { opacity: 0; width:0; height: 0; }
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/EPjsE/